# Lagrange multiplier over two constraints

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I'm having two constraints $g_{1}$=$x+y-z+2=0$ and $g_{2}$=$z^{2}-x^{2}-y^{2}=0$
and I want to determine the point on the intersection which is closest to the origin. The question asks us to use Lagrange multiplier over two constraints, so I need to minimize $F(x,y,z)= x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}$

According to $∇F=λ∇g_{1}+μ∇g_{2}$ I got the following equations

$$2x=λ+μ(-2x)$$

$$2y=λ+μ(-2y)$$

$$2z=-λ+μ(2z)$$

$g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$

from the first and second equation I got $2x+2μx=2y+2μy$, which is

$x(1+μ)=y(1+μ)$

In this case do I assume $1+μ$ is not equal to $0$? In this case I can get $x=y$ and the equation is quite simple to solve.

Or do I need to consider the situation when $1+μ=0$?

There is another case for this equation to be true, that is when $1+μ=1$, that is when $μ=0$

So I need to consider all three possible solutions of $μ$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Also, well done for showing your working! :)